# Local ring at generic point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, localization

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and $Y$ a subvariety of codimension one (both are irreducible).
I want to show that the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y,X}$ at the subvariety $Y$ (which is nothing but the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\eta,X}$ at the generic point $\eta$ of $Y$) is a discrete valuation ring.

I know the following:

- The local ring $\mathcal{O}_{P,X}$ at any point $P \in X$ (closed or not) is regular. (If $P$ is closed, this is the definition of "smooth", and any local ring at a non-closed point is a localisation of a local ring at a closed point, whence regular).
- Any Noetherian regular local ring of (Krull) dimension one is a discrete valuation ring.

It seems I need to prove that $\dim \mathcal{O}_{Y,X} = 1$, and since $Y$ is of codimension one in $X$, this would follow from the more general fact that for any subvariety $Z \subset X$, $\dim \mathcal{O}_{Z,X} = \text{codim}_{X} Z$.

My question is: Is this reasoning correct, and if yes, how do I prove it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the right plan! You want to show that the subvarieties containing $Z$ correspond to primes of $\mathcal{O}_{Z, X}$. At the affine level this just follows from the basic facts relating the prime ideal structure of a ring and its localization.

Comment: Thanks! I could finally solve it.